# Return Value From A Named Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am learning things from the ground up and trying to understand how to get values from functions better. Consider the following examples.

```
/* Screen Orientation Check */
function screenOrientation () {
    var screenOrientationCheck = ($(window).width() > $(window).height())? 90 : 0;
    console.log(screenOrientationCheck) ;
}
screenOrientation();
```

Above gives me the screen orientation.

```
/* Viewport Height Check */
function viewportHeight () {
    var viewportHeightCheck = document.documentElement.clientHeight
    console.log('viewportHeight = '+viewportHeightCheck);
};
viewportHeight();
```

This would give me the viewport height.

But now if I like to work with the results of those functions I am not sure how to do that.

```
if ( viewportHeight() > 600 ) {
    console.log('Hooray!!');
};
```

For example, this never fires.

```
if ( screenOrientation() === 90 ) {
    console.log('Hooray!!');
};
```

Likewise this also never fires.

If I like to log `screenOrientationCheck` or `viewportHeightCheck` it is `undefined` because the variables only exist in the scope of the function. That much I have understood. Adding `return` to either functions like below also does not do the trick.

```
/* Viewport Height Check */
function viewportHeight () {
    var viewportHeightCheck = document.documentElement.clientHeight
    console.log('viewportHeight = '+viewportHeightCheck);
    return viewportHeightCheck;
};
```

I know this is basic stuff. Therefore I am sorry to take your valuable time to ask this.

I am trying to understand how I can work with values created in functions and call those again and again in the code instead of having anonymous functions that are executed on the run and only once.

If someone out there has the nerve to answer this as detailed as possible, perhaps with an example that will log `Hooray!!` in the end, well that would be a good end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to **return** the value. Here's a working [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4khgjjs5/4/)

```
function getViewportHeight() {
    var viewportHeightCheck = document.documentElement.clientHeight
    return viewportHeightCheck;
};

if ( getViewportHeight () > 600 ) {
    console.log('Hooray!!');
};
```

Comment: The question to ask is how this is different from the OPs last example which apparently didn't work?

Comment: I selected this as answer because it uses the variable for the `return` value like outlined in my question. Though it did also help me tons to see @[juliobetta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/561610/juliobetta) answer with the function instruction behind `return`. I do have exact same code here so either the browser cache was not fully emptied or the page properly reloaded or the browser window too small for the px in height I had. After posting the question I left for a couple hours, reloaded the page upon return (pun) and everything was OK. Though it is great to have this confirmed.

Answer (score 1):

In your specific case, these functions should be returning a value, so every time they are called, you'll get a value according to the page dimensions.

```js
/* Screen Orientation Check */
function screenOrientation () {
  return ($(window).width() > $(window).height())? 90 : 0;
}


/* Viewport Height Check */
function viewportHeight () {
  return document.documentElement.clientHeight
};


$('#action').on('click', function() {
  $('#info').html('Screen Orientation: ' + screenOrientation() + '<br>' + 
                  'Viewport Height: ' + viewportHeight());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="info"></div>

<p>
  <button id="action">Get Values</button>
</p>
```